# Exclude Directory during rsync

Tags: backup, rsync

Hello I am trying to sync data between my to server using below command

```
rsync -avzP --exclude /home/username/public_html/raj/sandip "-e ssh -p 18765" username@c45562.server.net:/home/username/public_html/raj/ /home/rajrathodbvn/public_html/raj/
```

I want exclude directory called `sandip` but even I try to exclude it, its getting copied. Let me know if I am missing something. I have both server centos7.

Thanks

Comment: CentOS7 is off topic here but on-topic on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude a directory, the following syntax is used in general:

```
rsync -avz --exclude 'directory' source/ destination/
```

Also, note that to specify an alternative port, `-e 'ssh -p PORT_NO'` is used and not `"-e ssh -p PORT_NO"`

So, try to run the following command :

```
rsync -avzP --exclude '/home/username/public_html/raj/sandip' -e 'ssh -p 18765' username@c45562.server.net:/home/username/public_html/raj/ /home/rajrathodbvn/public_html/raj/
```

This syntax has been verified on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: +1, Good catch :-) You identified another problem, than the OP pointed to. General comment: In the manual `man rsync` the syntax is -`-exclude=PATTERN`, but I tested (in 18.04.1 LTS), and it works with a space instead of the equal sign.

Comment: This doesn't work. Directory is copied nonetheless.

Comment: When excluding files or directories you need to use their relative paths to the source directory. `rsync -avzP --exclude 'sandip' "-e 'ssh -p 18765' username@c45562.server.net:/home/username/public_html/raj/ /home/rajrathodbvn/public_html/raj/`